# подсчитать кол-во столбцов которые не повторяются

Tags: php

есть таблица в которой некоторые IP  повторяются, нужно посчитать сколько IP в таблице, те что повторяются не считать

```
$res = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visits GROUP BY ip");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
echo $row[0];
```

**так возврарается результат 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT( ip ) ) FROM visits
```

Comment: да это то что нужно))